# Adding custom views to admin panel in django

Tags: django, mongodb, admin, pymongo

I'm generating analytics using mongodb, now my functionality views are ready. Now I would like to move the views to admin panel. How do i do it, i'm using pymongo for interacting with mongodb.

Comment: This was already asked several times here. Please search before asking a question.

Comment: @Thibault : Yeah i found some links, but i thought it wouldn't work with mongodb. As i'm a beginner in django.

Answer (score 2):

[Adding views to admin sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites).